# How to use the kindle uri scheme in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uri

i want to open the kindle application from my own app and need to open specific file (included in the resources folder), i´ve been looking for the uri scheme in kindle but there is no information, does anyone knows how it works?

In my code i can open the app, but doesn't launch a book, 
the need is to open the application and open a specific pdf file found in the folder resources

```
Xamarin.Forms.Device.OpenUri(new Uri("kindle://book/?action=open&book_id=AMZNID0/0BWUTJQ/0/"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that  parameters are correct ？

Comment: I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779584/how-to-open-kindle-ebook-from--android but I'm not sure it's working, besides, that's not my need.